# Fibonacci Matrix

Tags: fibonacci

For calculating a fibonacci sequence in O(logn) we use matrix exponential since the term
`fn = fn-1 + fn-2` is linear but what is the matrix required if we want to find nth term of

`fn = fn-1 + fn-2 + a0 + a1*n + a2*n^2 + ... an*n^n`
which is a dependent on polynomial???
Here a0,a1,... an are constants

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, [*Fibonacci Matix*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FibonacciQ-Matrix.html) is described as something different than what you refer to.

Comment: no i m asking correct, a matrix which when exponentiated gives the nth term of the sequence..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the question is then...

Answer (score 1):

Look here for [implementation in Erlang](https://gist.github.com/pichi/8238258) which uses formula
[image: \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}^{n-1}=\begin{pmatrix}\mathrm{fib}(n)&\mathrm{fib}(n-1)\ \mathrm{fib}(n-1)&\mathrm{fib}(n-2)\end{pmatrix}]
. It shows nice linear resulting behavior because in `O(M(n) log n)` part `M(n)` is exponential for big numbers. It calculates fib of one million in 2s where result has 208988 digits. The trick is that you can compute exponentiation in `O(log n)` multiplications using (tail) recursive formula (tail means with `O(1)` space when used proper compiler or rewrite to cycle):

```
% compute X^N
power(X, N) when is_integer(N), N >= 0 ->
    power(N, X, 1).

power(0, _, Acc) ->
    Acc;
power(N, X, Acc) ->
    if N rem 2 =:= 1 ->
            power(N - 1,   X,     Acc * X);
        true ->
            power(N div 2, X * X, Acc)
    end.
```

where `X` and `Acc` you substitute with matrices. `X` will be initiated with [image: \begin{pmatrix}1&1\1&0\end{pmatrix}] and `Acc` with identity `I` equals to [image: \begin{pmatrix}1&0\0&1\end{pmatrix}].